# Mongoose: Bulk insert via Model.collection.insert crashes Node.js with Segmentation fault 11

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 10,000,000 documents that I want to insert into a MongoDB.

I use mongoose to create the documents of the parsed JSON (the JSON is created by transforming the content of a lot of txt files).

I started using `Model.create` for each document, but it was way to slow and would need several days to complete the operation.
So I switch to `Model.collection.insert` to speed things up.

This is my `saveToDB` function (written in TypeScript):

```
private saveToDB(hand: Hand): void {
    this.bulkHands.push(new HandHistory(hand));

    if(this.bulkHands.length >= 10000) {
        HandHistory.collection.insert(this.bulkHands, (err): void => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('error', err);
            }

            this.bulkHands = [];
        });
    }
}
```

I tried the code and my Parser builds up the array to 10,000 documents and then tries to insert them into the db. But Node always crashes with `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Even when I set the limit to 1 (inserting one document at a time), this happens. So I'm guessing it has something to do with the `Model.collection.insert` function. But my knowledge about the underlying structure is not deep enough to understand what is going on here.

Has anybody encountered such an issue? And what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem is that I push mongoose Model instances into the array. But only plain objects are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this would be a comment, but I can't post comments since I have low reputation points, but I feel this information would be useful to someone.

The accepted answer is the correct answer, but I just wanted to say that I was receiving a different error just in case anyone else runs into the same problem. I was inserting 10 million records as well and received the following error message:

```
{ '0': 
   { [MongoError: key $__ must not start with '$']
     name: 'MongoError',
     message: 'key $__ must not start with \'$\'' },
  '1': undefined }
```

As you can see, the error message was not helpful at all.

I passed in mongo Models instead of just plain old JSON. Thanks for the help.